# GIT GUI can't access welcome screen

Tags: git, git-gui

[image]I am trying to work on a new repository in my GIT GUI

but when ever i open GIT GUI ,it directly takes me to the second page and opens some previous repository

Attach is the screenshot

How can i switch my project , How can i get the Git-GUI welcome screen?

Comment: what commands do you issue? are you sure the created repo is correct? what gives `git status` in new repo?

Comment: i am opening Git GUI from my desktop and i see this window , No commands used .

Comment: what version are you using? when I launch Git-GUI I always get the first screen

Comment: gui version 0.16 ,  yeah i also saw the first screen first time , but now whenever i open it ,it shows the second one m i restarted it , restart my computer , but no luck ..

Comment: sounds like a bug...  Can you send an email to git@vger.kernel.org describing the problem?

Comment: email not delivering to this email due to some technical faults , i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in GitGUI. But you can still specify what folder to open by launching it from Explorer in the folder of the repository . Just right-click on the repository's folder and select "Git-GUI Here"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it for myself.

If you created a repository in your git root by entering commands versus using the GUI (in my case in c:/users/Adal), that seems to be what causes the GUI to jump straight to that repo every time. Just go ahead and delete that .git folder in c:/users/Adal or wherever your root is.

Worked for me ;-)