# Git GUI -- how to get back to opening screen

Tags: git, git-gui

When I launch Git GUI afresh, it gives me the following welcome screen:

[image]

Then, after opening one (of many) existing repositories on my local machine, I get to the screen below:

[image]

However, from here, I want to go back to the original welcome screen and open a different local repository. That does not seem to be possible. The only options under `Repository` are:

[image]

and none of these help to "Open Existing Repository".

A related question was asked earlier 9 or so years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223324/git-gui-cant-access-welcome-screen). The answer seemed to suggest that this is a bug in Git Gui. Is it still a bug? Is there a work around?

As of now, if I want to open a different repository, I have no option but to close current running instance of Git Gui followed by opening the Git Gui application again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior comes from the [`git-gui.sh`](http://choose_repository) which, when it does *not* detect a `$GIT_DIR` (`.git`), will call `choose_repository`

```bash
set picked 0
if {[catch {
        set _gitdir $env(GIT_DIR)
        set _prefix {}
        }]
    && [catch {
        # beware that from the .git dir this sets _gitdir to .
        # and _prefix to the empty string
        set _gitdir [git rev-parse --git-dir]
        set _prefix [git rev-parse --show-prefix]
    } err]} {
    load_config 1
    apply_config
    choose_repository::pick
    set picked 1
}
```

And [`git-gui/lib/choose_repository.tcl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/142430338477d9d1bb25be66267225fb58498d92/git-gui/lib/choose_repository.tcl) is the Tcl module which display the "opening screen".

It is called only from the starting script, and never again.

This has been set/decided in Sep. 2007, 14 years ago, in [commit ab08b36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab08b3630414dfb867825c4a5828438e1c69199d)

> ### git-gui: Allow users to choose/create/clone a repository

> If we are started outside of a git repository than it is likely
> the user started us from some sort of desktop shortcut icon in
> the operating system.
>
> In such a case the user is expecting us to
> prompt them to locate the git repository they want to work on,
> or to help them make a new repository, or to clone one from an
> existing location.
>
> This is a very simple wizard that offers the
> user one of these three choices.

This choice has never been updated seen, so it is not so much a "bug".
This seems to be working "as designed".

---

[WebViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597758/webviewer) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333584/git-gui-how-to-get-back-to-opening-screen/68333848?noredirect=1#comment131675663_68333848):

> When Git GUI prompts for "`Open Existing Repository`", the user should select the directory containing the `.git` subdirectory, not the `.git` one.

Comment: Ah, so it is a feature. Then, I suppose, as the accepted answer specifies in the linked to question, I should navigate to the folder, right click and open `git gui here`.

Comment: I would also add that when Git GUI prompts for "Open Existing Repository", the user should select the directory **containing** the `.git` subdirectory, not the .git one.

Comment: @WebViewer Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.